# Compatibility Ubuntu with GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UD5H-WB WIFI

Tags: drivers, hardware

I want to buy a [GIGABYTE GA-Z77X-UD5H-WB WIFI motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4167#sp).
Can I install Ubuntu or another Linux OS on a computer with this motherboard?

If this is possible: where I can download the drivers for this motherboard or are they already in the Ubuntu installation package?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've read on the specs it looks as though you should be good to go. I've used GIGABYTE motherboards before and they work out of the box. No need to install additional drivers, that is unless you have a dedicated video card. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a problem with sound on the GA-Z77-UD5H, requiring a workaround at the moment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/996245

UPDATE, days later: it seems there's a solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/996245/comments/30